# Why do I get Error #2004 while passing two strings to a function in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, exception

My Function's definition :

```
public function updateTextField(value:String, label:String):void{
.....
}
```

I call it as below :

```
updateTextField("Level : 1 Passed","L1");
```

And I get below error while debugging it using FDB, and the function's content isn't updated ( Textfield isn't updated ) :

```
"[Fault] exception, information=ArgumentError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid."
```

As far as I can understand, my function expects two strings, and that's why I provide it with.
.
I added a try-catch block when I call the function.

```
        try{
            updateTextField("Level : 1 Passed","L1");
        } catch(e1:ArgumentError) {
            trace("1. " + e1);
        }
```

Now , though it throws exception, but before that the function gets executed successfully. Though, it solves my problem up to an extent (except I will have to call the function inside try-catch every time)
But I would like to understand why I get such error when correct arguments are bring passed, and how could I rectify it ?

Comment: Please post the body of the function. Use the debugger to step through the function and see what's going on.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is about that function ? Also try to use [the ... (rest) parameter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56__WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f49) to see if you have always the error ...

Comment: Maybe the error is inside the function